# `ps` reports itself as using 99% CPU

Tags: process, 23.04

After update to Ubuntu 23.04, I noticed that the `ps` command ***sometimes*** reports itself as using 99% CPU.

If you try several times, you will see something like:

```
$ ps -ef | grep \ p[s]
my_user    48167    7979  0 21:11 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef

$ ps -ef | grep \ p[s]
my_user    48169    7979 99 21:12 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Note the `99` in the second case. This does repeat every time. Most of the times you will get  `0`, as in the first example.

This ***did not*** happen in previous versions of Ubuntu. I have a script that ran for more than 8 years on several systems with versions ranging from 14.04 to 22.10 (LTS and non-LTS) and never noticed such a thing.

The current version of `ps` is 4.0.3. Linux kernel is 6.2.0.

Should this be considered as a bug or a feature?

See also [another related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743701/).

Comment: "This did not happen in previous versions of Ubuntu."  It does on my 22.04 Budgie install :)

Comment: Trust me @Rinzwind it didn't and doesn't; I have several Ubuntu 22.04 systems. What is the version of your `ps`? What is your Linux kernel version? Did you really get the second output (with the `99`)?